# static variable initiator in Java

Tags: java, static

I don't understand the difference between A and B.

**A**

```
private static final CookieStore sCookieStore;
static {
    sCookieStore = new CookieStore();
}
```

**B**

```
private static final CookieStore sCookieStore = new CookieStore();
```

Is there somebody who can clarify my understanding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: When is a static initialization block useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379426/java-when-is-a-static-initialization-block-useful)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're effectively equivalent in your example.  B is shorter, and preferred for simple creations, but A allows more complicated intialization.

E.g.

```
private static final CookieStore sCookieStore;

static {
  sCookieStore = new CookieStore();
  sCookieStore.setSize(1000);
  sCookieStore.addToBlacklist("bing.com");
  sCookieStore.readCookiesFromFile("/tmp/cookies.txt");
}
```

Comment: Fantastic ! didnt knew that. Does something like that also exists for non-static object or it has to be in the constructor ?

Comment: @user978548 - There are instance initializer blocks for exactly what you're thinking of. See this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: This is also useful when the CookieStore constructor can throw an Exception.

Comment: @PaulBellora - I've been writing Java for something like 7 years, and I'd honestly never seen the instance initializer block.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

In your example, they do the same thing. A separate `static` block is useful if you have more than a single statement, and also if you need to handle exceptions thrown by those statements.