# Why Below Code outputs 10 3 times while I created only single object

Tags: java, enums

I did not understand why below code outputs 10 3 times.

```
enum Enums {
    A, B, C;
    private Enums() {
        System.out.println(10);
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Enum en = Enums.B;
    }
}
```

It outputs as :

```
10 10 10
```

Comment: Three objects were created (`Enums.A`, `Enums.B`, `Enums.C`), but you only used one (`Enums.B`). Enums are singleton objects and Java creates them for you.

Comment: Yes, but it outputs 10 three times. That's what I didn't get.

Comment: Try adding `D` as a value to the enum, and `10` will print 4 times :-)

Comment: every time it creates constant the constructor get executed and print 10, since you have three constants, constructor got executed three times @DattatrayaShinde

Comment: Interesting interview question :D

Answer (score 4):

Printing a constant `10` in your custom enum constructor (which you don't actually need here) is likely confusing you (and it isn't particularly meaningful regardless). Instead pass a value in to the constructor and see the reality of your three constant instances being instantiated. Like,

```
enum Enums {
    A(1), B(2), C(3);
    private Enums(int v) {
        System.out.printf("%s %d%n", this, v);
    }
}
```

Which will now output

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

Corresponding to `A`, `B` and `C`. You might also consider (in `main`)

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Enums.values()));
```

Which yields

```
[A, B, C]
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand why you're seeing the constructor called multiple times, we'll have a look at what happens behind the screen.

Starting with a simple `Enums.java`:

```
enum Enums { A, B; }
```

We'll compile, then immediately decompile to see what Java actually does with it internally:

```
javac Enums.java && javap -c Enums
```

which gives the following result (I'll cut a lot for brevity, but keep the important bits):

```
final class Enums extends java.lang.Enum<Enums> {

    public static final Enums A;
    public static final Enums B;

    ...
    static {}; //<-- Static initialiser
        Code:
            //Construct a new object, assign it to A
             0: new           #4   // class Enums
             3: dup
             4: ldc           #7   // String A
             6: iconst_0           // 0
             7: invokespecial #8   // Method "<init>":(LString;I)V <-- calls the parent constructor with "string A" and "const 0" above
            10: putstatic     #9   // Field A:LEnums;

            //Construct another, assign it to B
            13: new           #4   // class Enums
            16: dup               
            17: ldc           #10  // String B
            19: iconst_1           // 1
            20: invokespecial #8   // Method "<init>":(LString;I)V <-- calls the parent constructor with "string B" and "const 1 above"
            23: putstatic     #11  // Field B:LEnums;

            ...
            45: return
}
```

What you have there are:

- Two `public static final` fields called `A` and `B`, and
- A [static initialiser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9379426/5623232), which contains two `new` statements that constructs both `A` and `B`.
- As all enums are descended from `java.lang.Enum<>`, the two `new` calls also invoke [the parent's constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,int)): `protected Enum​(String name, int ordinal)` to give `A` and `B` a name and a numeric order.

The **static initialiser** you see above is the cause of you seeing multiple calls to your `println()`, even though you are only using one of the enums. The nature of static initialisers is that it gets called when you first use a class.

And as you can see in the code produced by the compiler, it will *immediately* construct both `A` and `B` (and `C` in your case), when you attempt to use your enum.