# Is it advisable to have a static block inside static inner class

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, singleton

I am in between an implementation where I am planning to use static block inside static Inner class.

This implementation is being done as part of lazy initialization of a singleton class.

I am not able to find any information on google if it is advisable or a good practice to do so?

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
public class MySingleton {

    private MySingleton() {
    }

    private static class InnerMySingleton {
        private static volatile MySingleton mysingleton;
        static {
            mysingleton = new MySingleton();
        }
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return MySingleton.InnerMySingleton.mysingleton;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom) and you could just do `private static final MySingleton mysingleton = new MySingleton();`

Comment: @michalk Well its a complex object to create this is not the actual code but a basic prototype. There are lot of steps involved in creating the actual object.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you could just go:

```
private static volatile MySingleton mysingleton = new MySingleton();
```

the static block doesn't add anything useful here. And in case it is more complicated, then don't use a static block, but

```
private static MySingleton makeSingleton() { ...
```

for example. Meaning: prefer a method over a nameless block (because that method can have a name that tells the reader what the method is supposed to do). `static` just says, well, "what follows happens static".

Second: when in doubt, try to write *less* code. There is really no advantage of static blocks for *simple* assignments. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379426/java-when-is-a-static-initialization-block-useful) for some reasoning.

Beyond that, you might want to study the CERT on [double locking](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/LCK10-J.+Use+a+correct+form+of+the+double-checked+locking+idiom) for example. There are myriads of ways to go about this.

Comment: Sorry my bad i didn't mentioned in the actual question that the code snippet provided is just an example of how i am using the static block in my singleton class. I have edited the question. There are multiple steps involved in creating the object and hence a single line declaration cannot be used